# Append data to heroku table

Tags: postgresql, heroku, import, heroku-toolbelt

I'm getting familiar with Heroku and need to import about 100 lines into one of the postgres tables on the heroku server.  I figure I can just import a table in its entirety using something like `heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE 'http://f.cl.l...3z18/mydb.dump'` but I would really like to just tack the lines onto the already existing table and let the id column auto-increment.  Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, courtesy of [this site](http://waelchatila.com/2014/02/22/1393108139145.html).

Just run this command:

```
psql `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a your_app`?ssl=true -c "\copy your_table FROM '/tmp/rows.csv' WITH CSV;"
```

Where `your_app` and `your_table` are replaced appropriately.